# How to solve the system $x_{t+1}=-x_t-2y_t+3t-2$, $y_{t+1}=-2x_t+2y_t+t+1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have the following system of recurrence equations:

> $$x_{t+1}=-x_t-2y_t+3t-2\qquad y_{t+1}=-2x_t+2y_t+t+1$$

I write this in matrix-vector form:
$$r_{t}=Ar_{t-1}+b\cdot (t-1)+c$$
I repeatedly apply the recurrence to get: 
$$r_t=A^tr_0+\left (\sum_{i=1}^t(t-i)A^{i-1}\right)b+\left (\sum_{i=1}^tA^{i-1}\right)c$$

> Does this count as a "solution"?
>   Is there a way to further simplify it?

Answer (score -1):

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_{t+1} \\ y_{t+1} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -2 \\ -2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_{t} \\ y_{t} \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}3t-2 \\ t+1 \end{bmatrix}$$
Now 
$$\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -2 \\ -2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}=RJR^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} \\ -\frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} \end{bmatrix}$$
Let
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_{t} \\ y_{t} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_{t} \\ b_{t} \end{bmatrix}, \ \forall{t}$$
Thus
$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_{t+1} \\ b_{t+1} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_{t} \\ b_{t} \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}3t-2 \\ t+1 \end{bmatrix}$$
Now multiply by
$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} \\ -\frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} \end{bmatrix}$$
To give
$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{t+1} \\ b_{t+1} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_{t} \\ b_{t} \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}\frac{6}{5}t-\frac{3}{5} \\ -\frac{t}{5}+\frac{4}{5} \end{bmatrix}$$
So you have decoupled the equations, they have a solution
$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{t} \\ b_{t} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-c_{1}2^{t} \\ c_{2}3^{t} \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{5}t-\frac{1}{3} \\ \frac{1}{4}t-\frac{9}{40} \end{bmatrix}$$
Thus
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_{t} \\ y_{t} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_{t} \\ b_{t} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{9t}{20}-\frac{107}{120} \\ \frac{9t}{10}-\frac{47}{40} \end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}c_{1}2^{t+1}+c_{2}3^{t} \\ c_{1}2^{t} -2c_{2}3^{t} \end{bmatrix}$$
Should be correct If i haven't messed the multiplications)

Comment: The step from $$\begin{bmatrix}a_{t+1} \\ b_{t+1} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_{t} \\ b_{t} \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}\frac{6}{5}t-\frac{3}{5} \\ -\frac{t}{5}+\frac{4}{5} \end{bmatrix}$$ to $$\begin{bmatrix}a_{t} \\ b_{t} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-c_{1}2^{t} \\ c_{2}3^{t} \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{5}t-\frac{1}{3} \\ \frac{1}{4}t-\frac{9}{40} \end{bmatrix}$$ surely lost the OP...

Comment: What is OP, sorry?

Comment: The user who asked the question.

Comment: And now that you know what OP means, what happens with the fact signalled in my comment?

Comment: So the solution has two terms, the first one is the homogeneous solution, which is easy to find via the substitution $(a_{t}, b_{t})=(c_{1}\alpha^{t}, c_{2}\beta^{t})$ and the second term is the particular solution which you find via the anzats $(a_{t}, b_{t})=(a_{1}{t}+a_{2}, b_{1}t+b_{2})$, rearrange and solve for $a_{i}, b_{i}$. Is it clearer?

Comment: Add this to the answer (ter repetita).